# How to get texfield value from alertview in ViewDidLoad? xcode iOS 5

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, csv

How can I get a textfield value from alertview in viewdidload function? and I want to use it in another function... Lets say the alertview text is myAlertviewText, then I want to use it in a different function as

```
NSString *outputfilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:myAlertviewText.text];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually pretty simple, use one of UIAlertView's delegate methods, and you can directly get the text value of the text view. Assuming that you've used an input alert view.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        //lets say this is the cancel button
    }else if (buttonIndex == 1){
        NSString *myString = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a custom alert view where you have added textField by yourself give that textField a unique Tag value (kTextFieldTag). Now in your `viewDidLoad` do as follows
(if your alert is showing otherwise you will get nil string):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    UITextField *txtTemp = [m_alertViewObject viewWithTag:kTextFieldTag];

    NSString *strTextFiledValue = txtTemp.text;
}
```